# Does $k$-th power of $p$ divide ${}_n\!C_r$ if the previous divides $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Does $p^k$ divide ${}_n\!C_r$ for all integer r if $p^k|n$ where $0\leq r \leq n$ and $p$ is prime?

Comment: What is ${}_n C_r$ ?

Comment: I think it's $\binom{n}{r}$ (the number of $k$-combinations of $n$/the binomial coefficient).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Take $p=3$, $n=6$, $k=1$, $r=3$. Then $p^k\mid n$ , but $p^k\nmid{}_n C_r$

Comment: Or $2^2\nmid{4\choose2}$. Or pretty much anything with $r=0$ or with $r=n$.